# Is it possible for a userland program to create a node in the linux sysfs filesystem?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I'd like to find a way for my userland program to create a node in the sysfs tree in order to integrate a piece of custom h/w, or virtual device the program manages with lmsensors framework.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Create a driver.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, as sysfs in fully managed by the kernel.

If you need to write a device driver and don't want to deal with kernel-space programming, you can google for Linux user-space device drivers (never implemented any, personally).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a simple device driver capable of creating /sys hwmon ‘virtual’ sensor and then added an ioctl/control interface to it so that I could inject commands from userland to add, update and delete nodes.  This was actually much more straightforward than I thought it might be.